# R: How to change item (or object) names of a data.table list?

Tags: r, split, data.table

I need a "split" of my data preserving my previous order and for that I used the data.table solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611734/r-split-preserving-natural-order-of-factors). I "split" my data according to two columns. See example below:

```
df = data.frame(product = c("b", "a", "b", "a"),
                value = c(sample(1:10,4)),
                year = c(2001, 2001, 2000, 2000))

require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, grp := .GRP, by = list(product,year)] 
setkey(dt, grp)
o2 <- dt[, list(list(.SD)), by = grp]$V1
```

this code returns the list without reordering by alpha or numerical. However, I want to change the items names into a mix of product and year.

```
> o2
[[1]]
   product value year
1:       b     3 2001

[[2]]
   product value year
1:       a     8 2001

[[3]]
   product value year
1:       b     4 2000

[[4]]
   product value year
1:       a     7 2000
```

The expected result should look like this:

```
> o2
$b.2001
   product value year
1:       b     3 2001

$a.2001
   product value year
1:       a     8 2001

$b.2000
   product value year
1:       b     4 2000

$a.2000
   product value year
1:       a     7 2000
```

Another split technique is also ok, but I need to keep my previous order. Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach it at the moment.

```
require(data.table)
tmp = setDT(df)[, list(grp=list(.SD)), by=.(product, year), .SDcols=names(df)]
setattr(ans <- tmp$grp, 'names', paste(tmp$product, tmp$year, sep="."))
ans
# $b.2001
#    product value year
# 1:       b     7 2001
# 
# $a.2001
#    product value year
# 1:       a     3 2001
# 
# $b.2000
#    product value year
# 1:       b    10 2000
# 
# $a.2000
#    product value year
# 1:       a     9 2000
```

I've added a [FR #1389](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1389) to provide a *split.data.table* method, with which this should be possible in one step.

But in most cases, it's easier to deal with one *data.frame*/*data.table* instead of a list. So providing a bit more insight into what your downstream tasks are might help figure out if this is really necessary..

Comment: thanks for your answer.. I have a large trade data set that have to split in the 94 product and 17 years and link to another dataset. Therefore I need the same order per year in order to link the dataset properly (the names are important for check as I do a few of calculation in between).

Answer (score 1):

Recent commits to data.table delivers `split` method. It is built on Arun's answer, and delivers some additional arguments for flexibility, read `?split` data.table method for details.

```
split(setDT(df), by=c("product","year"))
#$b.2001
#   product value year
#1:       b     4 2001
#
#$a.2001
#   product value year
#1:       a     5 2001
#
#$b.2000
#   product value year
#1:       b     6 2000
#
#$a.2000
#   product value year
#1:       a     7 2000
```

Installing current development data.table can be done by

```
install.packages("data.table",
                 repos="https://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table",
                 type="source")
```

Other two provided solutions, one by OP and by Arun, are also valid and will be supported too, unit tests were added to ensure that. If you write new code you should definitely use split method for readability.