# Sort list of strings by order of numeric parts

Tags: r, list, sorting, dataframe

I have a list of paths of files, which I want to sort in ascending order based on the first path of each list. The list of paths is show

```
$`HG-U133_Plus_2`
[1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/22"
[2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/23"
[3] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/24"
[4] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/25"

$`HG-U133A`
[1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/0"
[2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/1"

$`HG-U133A_2`
[1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/6" 
[2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/7" 
[3] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/8" 
[4] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/9" 
[5] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/10"
```

For sorting I tried the following code

```
lpath[order(sapply(lpath, function(x) sub('.*\\/', '', x[[1]][1]), simplify=TRUE))]
```

and

```
lpath[order(sapply(lpath, function(x) x[1]), simplify=TRUE))]
```

and result does not come as expected, which is shown below. The first list is fine but second and third are not.

```
$`HG-U133A`
[1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/0"
[2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/1"


$`HG-U133_Plus_2`
[1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/22"
[2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/23"
[3] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/24"
[4] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/25"


$`HG-U133A_2`
 [1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/6" 
 [2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/7" 
 [3] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/8" 
 [4] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/9" 
 [5] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/10"
```

**Expected Result**

```
$`HG-U133A`
[1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/0"
[2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/1"


$`HG-U133A_2`
 [1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/6" 
 [2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/7" 
 [3] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/8" 
 [4] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/9" 
 [5] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/10"


$`HG-U133_Plus_2`
[1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/22"
[2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/23"
[3] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/24"
[4] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/25"
```

Comment: What if you combine all lists into a data.frame, add an identifier where they came from, sort them, split again by the identifier et voila? If you make a minimal, easy to paste reproducible example, I can show you.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Would you post your solution based on sample data below. I was wondering if the're an easy answer in base R. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your paths has the same pattern and only last number changes then you can use `mixedorder` from `gtools` package; otherwise, think about using `gsub` and regular expression.

```
L[mixedorder(sapply(L, function(x) x[1], simplify=TRUE), decreasing=FALSE)]
```

`L` is the list containing your paths.

## Example:

For the sample data provided below this would be the answer:

```
#Original List before sorting:
# > L
# [[1]] 
# [1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/22" 
# [2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/30" 
#  
# [[2]] 
# [1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/0" 
# [2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/9" 
# [3] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/5" 
#  
# [[3]] 
# [1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/6" 
# [2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/7" 
# [3] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/8" 
#
```

Sorted list based on the first element:

```
L[mixedorder(sapply(L, function(x) x[1], simplify=TRUE), decreasing=FALSE)]
# [[1]] 
# [1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/0" 
# [2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/9" 
# [3] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/5" 
#  
# [[2]] 
# [1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/6" 
# [2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/7" 
# [3] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/8" 
#  
# [[3]] 
# [1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/22" 
# [2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/30" 
#
```

**Sample Data**

```
L <-
 list(c("C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/22",  
 "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/30" 
 ), c("C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/0",  
 "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/9",  
 "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/5" 
 ), c("C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/6",  
 "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/7",  
 "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/8"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a base R solution.

```
L <-
  list("HG-U133_Plus_2" = c("C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/22",  
         "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/30"), 
  "HG-U133A" = c("C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/0",  
       "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/1",  
       "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/2"), 
  "HG-U133A_2" = c("C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/6",  
       "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/7",  
       "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/8"))

# map which element comes from which list element
L <- mapply(FUN = function(x, y) {
  data.frame(x, names = y)
}, x = L, y = as.list(names(L)), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
L <- do.call(rbind, L) # put everything in one data.frame
L$x <- as.character(L$x)
rownames(L) <- NULL # fore pretty printing

# find last element of the path
find.last.number <- gsub(".*/(\\d+)$", "\\1", L$x)
# find.last.number <- basename(L$x) # alternative if it's a file path
find.last.number <- as.numeric(find.last.number)
L <- L[order(find.last.number), ] # sort based on the last element of the path

# you need to reorder L$names factor to preserve the order for split, see
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611734/r-split-preserving-natural-order-of-factors
# split based on list element origin
split(L$x, f = factor(L$names, levels = unique(L$names)))

$`HG-U133A`
[1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/0"
[2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/1"
[3] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/2"

$`HG-U133A_2`
[1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/6"
[2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/7"
[3] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/8"

$`HG-U133_Plus_2`
[1] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/22"
[2] "C:\\Users\\agaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp0wZI21/008947515435900b4d1a0b8d/30"
```

Comment: A single line solution using `iterators::iter`: `L[order(sapply(iter(L),function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x[1],"/"))[3])))]`

Comment: @ChiPak the request was using base packages only.